# combine two array each element and append to one array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, xcode

I have two array like below. I need to combine two array each data and append to one array. The example are :

```
var d1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var d2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
var d3  = [String]()

//O/P needed : ["1-A","2-B","3-C","4-D","5-E"]
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when the arrays are of unequal length? Why is the data source formatted like this? Why not use a single array of a *struct* instead of two arrays? **More importantly** - What have you tried so far?

Comment: use `Zip` concept - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of **`zip(_:_:)`** and **`map(_:)`** over `d1` and `d2` like so,

```
let d3 = zip(d1, d2).map({ $0.0 + "-" + $0.1})

print(d3) //["1-A", "2-B", "3-C", "4-D", "5-E"]
```

In case any one of the `arrays` have extra elements, those extra ones will be ignored while performing the `zip` operation.

Comment: can u please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926400/not-able-to-get-the-exact-content-height-in-wkwebview

Comment: @teja the question has been deleted I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var d2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
var d3  = [String]()

//O/P needed : ["1-A","2-B","3-C","4-D","5-E"]
// works for diff length of d2
func mergArray(firstArray: [String], secondArray: [String]) -> [String] {
    for (index,val) in d1.enumerated() {
       guard index < d2.count else {
       d3.append(val)
       return d3
   }
   d3.append(val + "-" + d2[index])
}
   return d3
}

print(mergArray(firstArray: d1, secondArray: d2))
```

Comment: can u please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926400/not-able-to-get-the-exact-content-height-in-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Do it like -

```
for i in 0..< d1.count {
    d3.append(d1[i] + "-" + d2[i])
}
print(d3)
```

You will have your desire result.

Comment: what happend if size are not same? your code will lead to crash.

Comment: I answered for that particular question and that seems very clear those array are of same length and yes if they were not then I use zip. That seems fair now.

Comment: @Abhishek can u please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926400/not-able-to-get-the-exact-content-height-in-wkwebview

Comment: Page not found, That question might be deleted